# Can a Dagger 2 dependency be non-injectable?

Tags: dagger-2

Is there a way to tell Dagger 2 how to provide something, but not allow it to be injected?

Say I want to inject a `Qux`.  A `Qux` requires a `Foo` and a `Bar`:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Foo foo() {
    return new Foo();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Bar bar() {
    return new Bar();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Qux qux(final Foo foo, final Bar bar) {
    return new Qux(foo, bar);
}
```

But what if I don't want `Foo` and `Bar` to be injectable?  Perhaps exposing them would break the encapsulation of the `Qux`, or perhaps they're factories of some kind that I only want the `Qux` to have access to.

I've thought of a couple ways I could achieve this:

- If the `Foo` singleton is needed by other providers, I could make it a class member.  But this would get messy if `Foo` has several dependencies of its own.
- If the `Bar` singleton is not needed by any other providers, I could create the instance inside the `Qux` provider.  But this would get messy if `Qux` has several dependencies like that.

Neither of these solutions seem very elegant or Daggery.  Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you're trying to do is to define a package-private qualifier.

```
package my.pkg;

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@interface ForMyPackage {}
```

Then, use that for your bindings for Foo and Bar:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@ForMyPackage
Foo foo() {
    return new Foo();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@ForMyPackage
Bar bar() {
    return new Bar();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Qux qux(final @ForMyPackage Foo foo, final @ForMyPackage Bar bar) {
    return new Qux(foo, bar);
}
```

That way, you can only request that those versions of Foo and Bar be injected if you have access to the qualifier.

If all of these bindings are in a single module, you can even use a private, nested qualifier in the module.

**Edit by asker:**

I tried the last suggestion.

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
private @interface NoInject {}

@Provides
@Singleton
@NoInject
Foo foo() { return new Foo(); }
```

Attempting to inject a `Foo` causes a compile-time error, as desired:

> Error:(15, 6) Gradle: error: com.mydomain.myapp.Foo cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
>   com.mydomain.myapp.MyActivity.foo
>   [injected field of type: com.mydomain.myapp.Foo foo]

So while the error message is a bit misleading, this technique is neat and effective.

Comment: Yes, if the bindings for `Foo` and `Bar` are in different packages from the binding for `Qux` then this won't work, but I would argue that if you want this relationship it is a little odd that it would cross the package boundary.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this sounds a lot like [component dependencies](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.5/dagger/Component.html).

> [..] As an alternative, components can use bindings only from another component interface by declaring a component dependency. When a type is used as a component dependency, each provision method on the dependency is bound as a provider. Note that only the bindings exposed as provision methods are available through component dependencies.

If you really want to hide your `Foo` and `Bar`, you could make the module, `Foo`, and `Bar` package local. Then create a component that only exposes `Qux` and use it as a component dependency.

Since `Foo` and `Bar` are package local, a `SubComponent` should not be able to use them, either.
Your component would be the only one able to use the module and thus create and use `Foo` and `Bar` in its dependency graph.

Answer (score 1):

A repost of my answer elsewhere...

A simple way to do this is:

```
@Retention(BINARY)
@Qualifier
private annotation class InternalApi

@Module
object NetworkModule {
  @Provides 
  @InternalApi 
  fun provideClient(): OkHttpClient {
    //...
  }

  @Provides
  fun provideRetrofit(
    @InternalApi client: Lazy<OkHttpClient>
  ): Retrofit {
    //...
  }
}
```

culled from [here](https://www.zacsweers.dev/dagger-party-tricks-private-dependencies/).

Basically, we create private qualifiers- in this case, `@InternalApi` that is used to qualify the `OkHttpClient` dependency thus making it private to our module.