# Dagger 2: avoid exporting private dependencies

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

Lets say I have a module where I only want to export an instance of `A`. However this `A` requires instances of `B`and `C` to be passed in the constructor. So we would declare them as well in the module:

```
public class SampleModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    A provideA(B b, C c){
        return new A(b, c);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    B provideB(){
        return new B();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    C provideC(){
        return new C(); 
    }
}
```

This works, but now `B` and `C` are also available elsewhere in the code. I want to keep them private and force client classes to only have access to `A`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219257/can-a-dagger-2-dependency-be-non-injectable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Dagger 2 dependency be non-injectable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219257/can-a-dagger-2-dependency-be-non-injectable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish that goal is to bind the types that you don't want to be made available (in this case `B` and `C`) with a [`@Qualifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Qualifier.html) that is not accessible.

Then, while `B` and `C` might be be accessible from outside the module, in order to inject them you would need to supply a qualifier, which is not.

```
@Module
public final class SampleModule {
  @Qualifier
  @Retention(RUNTIME)
  private @interface SampleModuleOnly {}

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  static A provideA(@SampleModuleOnly B b, @SampleModuleOnly C c){
    return new A(b, c);
  }

  @Provides
  @SampleModuleOnly 
  @Singleton
  static B provideB(){
    return new B();
  }

  @Provides
  @SampleModuleOnly 
  @Singleton
  static C provideC(){
    return new C(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok this works but messes with all provided dependencies marked with `@Named` annotation. It happens to also be a qualifier and you cant have two qualifiers in a `provideXXX` method.

Comment: Yes, that is one of many reasons to prefer custom qualifiers to `@Named`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this is

```
@Retention(BINARY)
@Qualifier
private annotation class InternalApi

@Module
object NetworkModule {
  @Provides 
  @InternalApi 
  fun provideClient(): OkHttpClient {
    //...
  }

  @Provides
  fun provideRetrofit(
    @InternalApi client: Lazy<OkHttpClient>
  ): Retrofit {
    //...
  }
}
```

culled from [here](https://www.zacsweers.dev/dagger-party-tricks-private-dependencies/).

Basically, we create private qualifiers- in this case, `@InternalApi` that is used to qualify the `OkHttpClient` dependency thus making it private to our module.