# Dagger 2 - Proper way to provide instances within a very own module only

Tags: dagger-2

Say I have something like this:

```
@Module
internal class SeenModule {
  @Provides
  fun parameter() = Parameter()

  @Provides
  fun actualThingINeedToInject(parameter: Parameter) = ActualThing(parameter)
}
```

However, this module only really needs to provide an ActualThing object - in other words, the Parameter is only there because the very own module needs it. I don't want it to be part of the set of dependencies that can be retrieved outside of this module.
The way I'm currently doing this is by defining a custom scope as private and then marking the methods that provide dependencies which shouldn't leave the module with this scope, as well as those in the module where the provided dependencies should be injected, of course. This is a bit annoying because it prevents me from using other scopes in these methods and requires a lot of additional annotating all over the place. What is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272652/dagger-2-avoid-exporting-private-dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dagger doesn't really offer "private bindings" in the sense you're asking for, where Parameter would not be injectable from anywhere else. I also advise against using scope annotations for visibility, in part because the Component itself would need to be annotated with that scope annotation, so the scope annotation would simply slightly increase the hassle needed to improperly consume Parameter (and the hassle needed to create a Component that properly consumes Parameter).

I'd offer one of these three alternatives:

1. Reduce the visibility of Parameter as a class. If Parameter is package-private, you won't be able to refer to it from outside of that Java package, giving you the encapsulation you want.
2. Use ["Subcomponents for Encapsulation"](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html#subcomponents-for-encapsulation), in which you create a subcomponent, install  your Parameter (and any related bindings) in a Module bound on the subcomponent, and expose only your ActualThing on the subcomponent's interface. Your subcomponent will be injectable, but your Parameter is not; you can also write a @Provides method that returns your ActualThing from your subcomponent instance.
3. Grin and bear it, and just document that Parameter is an implementation detail that should not be accessed outside of certain packages. If you are providing objects to external teams who access ActualThing through your Component interface, you can simply decline to put Parameter on your public interface; if you are providing objects to internal teams they will likely have access to change your Dagger structure or access modifiers anyway. You might also ask yourself why Parameter would be useful for another team to consume, and document it as an API if there is a business reason for injecting it.

Comment: Number 2 definitely seems like the proper way to do things. Thanks for the help!