# Better Dagger encapsulation

Tags: java, dagger-2

I'm using Dagger across several Gradle modules in an android project. I have a lib and app module. Inside `lib` module I have two classes `PrivateThing` and `ExposedThing`. `ExposedThing` depends on `PrivateThing`.

I have a dagger @Module to provide these two things:

```
@Module
public class LibModule {
    @Provides
    ExposedThing provideExposedThing(PrivateThing privateThing) {
        return new ExposedThing(privateThing);
    }

    @Provides
    PrivateThing providePrivateThing() {
        return new PrivateThing();
    }
}
```

In the `app` module, I have a single class `SomeUiElement` which depends on `ExposedThing` and a separate module:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    @Provides
    SomeUiElement provideSomeUiElement(ExposedThing exposedThing) {
        return new SomeUiElement(exposedThing);
    }
}
```

And a component to bring everything together:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        ApplicationModule.class,
        LibModule.class
})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(SomeActivity activity);

}
```

Now I want to enforce that nothing in the `app` module can depend on `PrivateThing`. I think I'm asking something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219257/can-a-dagger-2-dependency-be-non-injectable). One solution was to use component dependency. However the documentation recommends subcomponents [see "Subcomponents for encapsulation"](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents).

Which is the preferred way to do this? Won't either method mean that `lib` module supplies it's own Component? I thought this was not a best practice, that libraries should only supply a Module.

Comment: Just being curious, either component dependency and sub-component can't prevent exposing `PrivateThing` to the application component, doesn't it?